# Add ProxyAddresses to separate script

Tags: powershell

Goal: Append script to add three different SMTP addresses.

Script: https://thesysadminchannel.com/how-to-create-o365-mailboxes-hybrid-exchange/

Code Snippet:

```
Write-Host "Continuing will create the AD account and O365 Email." -ForegroundColor:Green
Write-Host
$Proceed = $null
$Proceed = Read-Host "Continue? (y/n)"

if ($Proceed -ieq 'y') {
      
    Write-Host "Creating the O365 mailbox and AD Account."
    New-RemoteMailbox -Name $fullname -FirstName $firstname -LastName $lastname -DisplayName 
   $fullname -SamAccountName $logonname -UserPrincipalName $logonname@$domain -PrimarySmtpAddress 
   $logonname@$domain -Password $password -OnPremisesOrganizationalUnit $OU -DomainController $Server
    Write-Host "Done..."
    Write-Host
    Write-Host
    Sleep 5


    Write-Host "Adding Properties to the new user account."
    Get-ADUser $logonname -Server $Server | Set-ADUser -Server $Server -Description $Description - 
    Office $Office -StreetAddress $StreetAddress -City $City -State $State -PostalCode $PostalCode - 
    Country $Country -Title $Title -Department $Department -Company $Company -Manager $Manager - 
    EmployeeID 
    $EmployeeID
    Write-Host "Done..."
    Write-Host
    Write-Host

    if ($MemberOf) {
        Write-Host "Adding Membership Groups to the new user account."
        Get-ADUser $logonname -Server $Server  | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Server $Server - 
    MemberOf $MemberOf
        Write-Host "Done..."
        Write-Host
        Write-Host
        }
    }  
     Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

What I'm trying to add are these three values:

```
SMTP:user@domain.com
smtp:user@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com
smtp:user@domain.onmicrosoft.com
```

This is along the lines of what I've come up with:

```
Write-Host "Adding Properties to the new user account."
    Get-ADUser $logonname -Server $Server | Set-ADUser -Server $Server -Description $Description     
    -Office $Office -StreetAddress $StreetAddress -City $City -State $State -PostalCode $PostalCode - 
    Country $Country -Title $Title -Department $Department -Company $Company -Manager $Manager - 
    EmployeeID $EmployeeID
    Write-Host "Done..."
    Write-Host
    Write-Host
    Write-Host “Setting up TCS E-mail Standard”
                $userinfo.ProxyAddresses = "SMTP:" + ($FirstInitial.Add(1)) +  ($userinfo.sn) + 
 "@DOMAIN.COM"
                #$userinfo.ProxyAddresses += "smtp:" + ($userinfo.givenname) + "." + ($userinfo.sn) + 
 "@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com"
                $userinfo.ProxyAddresses += "smtp:" +  ($FirstInitial.Remove(1)) + ($userinfo.sn) + 
 "@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
                $userinfo.targetAddress = "SMTP:" +   ($userinfo.sAMAccountName)  + 
 "@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com"
    Write-Host "Done..."
    Write-Host
```

Then I get this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Temp\CreateStudentEmail.ps1:233 char:21
+ ...             $userinfo.ProxyAddresses = "SMTP:" + ($FirstInitial.Add(1 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Temp\CreateStudentEmail.ps1:235 char:21
+ ...             $userinfo.ProxyAddresses += "smtp:" +  ($FirstInitial.Rem ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The property 'targetAddress' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can                         
be set.
At C:\Users\Temp\CreateStudentEmail.ps1:236 char:21
+ ...             $userinfo.targetAddress = "SMTP:" +   ($userinfo.sAMAccou ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Just trying to find a way to incorporate the proxy address section so that I don't have to worry about extra steps.

I pulled the code from another PowerShell I used years ago, then tweaked it a bit, but it DOES actually input SMTP address fields into the AD character. It still throws errors though.

Comment: I can't even make out what format you're wanting the username to be. Where did you collect first initial? Do you want all 3 to be `f.lastname@` ?

Comment: Ah, forgive me. I scrubbed some of that information. We use a FiLastXX format. So GeWashington25@domain.com, though in most Hybrid environment you get:

SMTP:GeWashington25@domain.com
smtp:GeWashington25@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com
smpt:GeWashington25@domain.onmicrosoft.com

When you use the SamAccountName in my script, it pulls the FiLastXX format.

    $fullname = "$lastname, $firstname"
    #Write-Host
    $i = 2
    $logonname = $firstname.substring(0,$i) + $lastname + $gyear

Comment: Where does variable `$userinfo` come from, as you never seem to capture any info of the user object. Also, you're adding newlines in the code in places where it breaks the code. Look a bit further on how to create users and set the properties. Especially,  start using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to add those addresses....  Do you have hybrid exchange mode set up in your environment?  Does your active directory sync with office 365?  Then you would need to make those changes to the on-prem object and let the changes sync up, wouldn't you?

Comment: I pulled it from a previous script at a job I used that did the ProxyAddresses attribute.

@WilliamHiggs - Yes, we have Hybrid Exchange on our site. AD syncs through the hybrid exchange server which then pushes to O365. The way our site works is this script connects to the On-Prem server and makes the Mailbox, but oddly it creates the user locally to the on-prem DCs, then pushes to the DC that is connected to our Exchange server which then pushes to O365.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
  set-Aduser $samaccountname -Add @{ proxyAddresses = "SMTP:user@domain.com","smtp:user@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com","smtp:user@domain.onmicrosoft.com" }
```